# how to use for each loop in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach

I have a table `tblEmpDetail` which contains a column `CreatedDate`.

I want to **add 72 hours** to each created date, so if the created date is `2012-07-14 07:21:19.180` then I want the output to be `2012-07-17 07:21:19.180`.

Can someone let me know how can I accomplish to this?

Actually what I want to do is to go to each row then check if the

```
getdate() - createddate
```

is equal to or less than 72 hours; then I need to add 72 hours to `createddate`. Otherwise I want that column to be null. I am pasting my code that what I have done.

```
Declare @PassedTime datetime
set @PassedTime= DATEDIFF(HH,Createddate, GETDATE())

if CONVERT(varchar(20),@PassedTime,108)>=CONVERT(varchar(20),'72:00:00',108)
begin
    select empno,empName,CreatedDate,dateadd(HH,72,CreatedDate)BD from tblEmpDetail 
end
else
begin
   select empno,empName,CreatedDate,'' as BD from tblEmpDetail
end
```

Comment: Just a tip from someone who has been at it a while. If you are writing a loop in SQL, you are doing it wrong. Try to rephraese the solution as a query.

Comment: I have edited the question please review it

Comment: Extra credit for calling `GetDate()` once and saving the value instead of chasing a moving target in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No looping is required.

SQL Server excels at doing "set based" queries.

To get a projection:

```
select
    CreatedDate,
    DateAdd(hour, 72, CreatedDate) [NewDate]
from
    tblEmpDetail
```

To update the table permanently:

```
update
    tblEmpDetail
set
    CreatedDate = DateAdd(hour, 72, CreatedDate)
```

If you MUST have a loop, you can use a cursor:

```
declare cur cursor fast_forward read_only for
select
    CreatedDate,
    DateAdd(hour, 72, CreatedDate) [NewDate]
from
    tblEmpDetail

-- here, you would use the cursor.
```

More information on cursors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

### EDIT

Your query above can be done in a set based way like this:

```
select
    CreatedDate,
    CASE
        WHEN DateAdd(hour, 72, CreatedDate) <= GetDate() THEN NULL
        ELSE DateAdd(hour, 72, CreatedDate)
    END [NewDate]
from
    tblEmpDetail
```

Comment: @raman: I have added an example of what you are trying to do.  I *might* have the logic backwards, but the idea is to use `CASE WHEN` as though it was an `IF` statement.